# Android layout_centerInParent property not working after adding a view programatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout which contain a `linearLayout` with two `imageView` as below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlParent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

           <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i have added custom `surfaceView` programmatically. After adding the `surfaceView` `linearLayout` is not showing in center.I tried to set `layout_centerInParent` property through the code but it is not working.

Please help me.

```
mPreview = new CustomSurfaceView(getActivity(),1, CameraPreview.LayoutMode.FitToParent, false,this);
   LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    mLayout.addView(mPreview, 0, previewLayoutParams);
```

mLayout is Releativelayout and mPreview  is custom surfaceview

Comment: can you add your java code where you are adding surfaceView programmatically ?

Comment: show how you are adding view programatically

Comment: Where you added the `surfaceView`, inside the LinearLayour or RelativeLayout?

Comment: I have added surfaceview inside relativelayout. Please check updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent layout(Here `RelativeLayout`) width must be `match_parent`. Then only your child layout, the `centerInParent` will work.

Comment: If surface view is not added the linear layout is showing in center

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/rlParent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlChild">

        ......

    </LinearLayout>
```

```
View mPreview = findViewById(R.id.rlChild);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mPreview.getLayoutParams();
previewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mPreview.setLayoutParams(previewLayoutParams);
mLayout.addView(mPreview);
```

Comment: set RelativeLayout's height and width as "match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

The second and the third lines, you have to write `match_parent`. That's why `centerinparent` doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Try this `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`